# passing nested dictionary in url request issue swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I am trying to pass a nested dictionary to the server using a URL request.

i try below dictionary format:

```
var pdictData = ["post_id":"JobListObj.JobID","comment":txtMsg.text,"rating[price]":viewPrice.rating,"rating[service]":viewService.rating,"rating[location]":viewLocation.rating,"rating[quality]":viewQuality.rating] as [String : Any]
```

it's not working at all shows me please pass the rating data

here is format suggested by my web api developer :

```
post_id:1830
comment:Rateing again
rating[quality]:1
rating[location]:1
rating[service]:1
rating[price]:1
```

Comment: The parameters should be URL encoded? Also, can you post a working example from let's say postman?

Comment: @matt tried with rating dictionary object not worked thanks.

Comment: @gcharita , Thanks its worked for me with the same parameter structure using url encoding.

Comment: If the problem is solved please answer your own question, or else delete it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This format looks stranger for me, probably you should pass this data on body of request instead of url parameters. Try share the API documentation  on your question (if it public).

I guess that you want send a data using post method. So, you need create a struct like this.

```
struct Job: Codable {
   let post_id: Int
   let comment: String 
   let rating: Rating  
}

struct Rating: Codable { 
   let quality: Int
   let location: Int
   let service: Int
   let price: Int
}
```

And then configue your request:

```
let job = Job( .... )
let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(job)
let url = URL(string: "MY_HOST")
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpBody = data
```